# Unlock the screen on a WP8 device programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8, screen

I want to make an alarm clock app which unlocks the screen and brings it up to full white brightness over a period of 2-3 minutes.

I've heard that it's not possible to unlock the screen programmatically. Does anyone know if this is true? I can't find any tech details on code to unlock the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unlock the phone from code.  The supported APIs just do not have the capability.

Comment: thanks, as a workaround I guess I can make the app hold the screen on and display a black screen (or possibly a clock)

Comment: You could try, but you won't pass certification if you do.  The only mechanisms for taking control over the device screen locking systems are checked for in depth during certification and if your app doesn't meet the requirements for accessing them (e.g. Your app plays video content) then it will not make it to the store.

Comment: You can however keep the screen on, and display the black screen in case the user explicitly agrees that it is the behavior he wants. You can't force him, but if you ask beforehand, that sreen will be kept on and she agrees, you are ok to do that. See this – http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I knew it was possible, as I've seen approved apps that can do it. Thanks!